# Associate Existing Image File with Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I'm creating a basic blog in Django. One of my classes is for the authors. Each contains Name, Position, Biography, etc., and I'm attempting to associate existing images with each author to be used as avatars, essentially.

FileField and ImageField aren't what I want to use as I already have images stored statically elsewhere- I just want to specify each image's path manually in the Django admin as a URL (CharField/TextField, whatever) and have that image served when I call {{ author.photo }} in a template, for example. I also don't necessarily want to source the image path from the class model, as the structure and paths of the existing images may change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to save it somewhere in order to map the user and the image....

So I can think of 2 solutions -

1. Have a field that stores the path. Then you can access it via the template, something like this - `<img src="{{author.photo_path}}">`
2. If you're saying the path might change, you can have a user ID for each user, and store his photo with that ID. Then you can simply do `<img src="/path/{{author.id}}_picture.gif">`

Using the second solution, you can also have the path as a variable in your code, and then pass it to the template, and access the picture like this - 
`<img src="/{{path}}/{{author.id}}_picture.gif">`, which doesn't force you to have a hardcoded path, and once the path changes you only change it once, not in all your model instances/template files

Comment: I like Thomas' 2nd solution. You could go one further though. You could have a FileField for author image, and then from the template do something like `{% if not author.image %}<img src="/{{path}}/{{author.id}}_picture.gif">{% else %}<img src="{{ author.image }}">{% endif %}`. That way, you can upload new or future images from the admin or your form or whatever.